# My grunt-regarde task is aborted if jshint detects an error

Tags: gruntjs

I expected grunt-regarde to go on watching for changes after a task is called.
This way I have to restart it (>grunt regarde) on the console each time a lint error was found.
Is grunt regarde supposed to behave like this or is this an issue with grunt-contrib-jshint and grunt-regarde?
Does this have something to do with the spawn option?

i was using grunt-contrib-watch before and it continued watching after jshint detected an error, which is want I expect regarde to do as well.

The reason why I started using regarde is that regard allows to just lint the changed file not the whole project, which is faster.

Here's my configuration:

```
grunt.initConfig({

    jshint: {
        file: '<%= grunt.regarde.changed %>'
    },

    regarde: {
            javascript: {
                files: '**/*.js',
                tasks: ['jshint:file']
    }

});
```

I use

node.js 0.8.21

grunt-cli 0.1.6

grunt 0.4.0rc7

grunt-contrib-jshint 0.2.0

grunt-regarde: 0.1.1

Comment: Turns out that this is an issue with grunt-regarde.

Comment: yep, set spawn:true - https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-regarde#spawn